# How should I safely initialize and then use a variable in different try blocks?

Tags: c#, file-io, scope, try-catch

So, I need to create a file using the StreamWriter class, write to it and then close it, and I want to put all the potentially inexecutable operations in try blocks; and as the file creation and write operations will be in different try blocks, I can't initialize the StreamWriter variable (create the file) in one try block and then use it in another. I guess I could declare the StreamWriter variable outside the try blocks and set it to null, then initialize it in a try block, but MSDN says "When inside a try block, only initialize variables that are declared therein; otherwise, an exception can occur before the execution of the block is completed". What is the best practice for safely declaring, initializing, using a file stream variable (or any variable, for that matter) and then disposing of it? Maybe I should use something instead of StreamWriter? Also, why shouldn't you initialize a variable in a try block if you hadn't declared it there?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StreamWriter's lifetime should be managed by a using block.

Your instinct to move the variable declaration outside of the two try blocks is correct if you want to access it from within both.  The MSFT guidance is just trying to impress upon you that in that case if you have possible exceptions occurring after declaration but before the try blocks they won't be caught, but initializing a variable to null will not throw an exception and if you don't do anything other than that you are fine. (If you were really worried about it though, you could just create a try/catch that encapsulates the variable declaration and also the other try blocks) Personally I am not a fan of a lot of try/catch but that's a sermon for another day...

Answer (score 3):

You can declare it outside of the try blocks, just make sure you handle proper disposal.

```
StreamWriter sw = null;

try
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
    sw.Write("Some text.");
}
catch
{
    // Whatever you want to catch
}
finally
{
    if(sw != null)
        sw.Dispose();

    sw = null;  
}


try
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open("otherfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
}
catch
{
    // Whatever you want to catch
}
finally
{
    if(sw != null)
        sw.Dispose();

    sw = null;  
}
```

Although, I wouldn't suggest using the same variable in multiple try blocks, what do you gain by doing that?

Why not something like this:

```
try
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open("text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
    {
        sw.Write("some text");
    }
}
catch
{
    // handle exception
}


try
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open("otherfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
    {
        sw.Write("some other text");
    }
}
catch
{
    // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is a `StreamWriter` defined at a classs level not a method? I would suggest to use a single try block if this is possible.

If you need to handle different exceptions use multiple `catch` blocks for single `try` as suggsted by [scottm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53007/scottm)

Comment: If you are going to handle different exception types, you can just use multiple catch statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a variable in two distinct try blocks, you need to declare it outside both of the blocks ( in some way ). That is simple scope control.

Why shouldn't you? I would guess that the reason is that you might hit an exception and not know if the variable is initialised. So the state at the end of the T/C/F block is indeterminate. If you can be sure that the state is determined then it is OK, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think what MSDN means is that it is possible that by declaring a variable of type `T` the static constructor of `T` might be called, causing an exception to be thrown outside the `try` block.

In your example I do not see any problems in declaring the variable outside the `try` block. Just do it like suggested by scottm.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the variable to null at the declaration is the same as initializing it. It just doesn't contain a valid reference to any real object, but you can test for that. You can't test for uninitialized variables: you'll get compilation errors if you have a possible path that leads to the use of an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your StreamWriter outside the try...catch block, but don't initialise it. Do the initialisation within the block. The MSDN article you refer to seems to suggest that's not a good idea, but I can't see why.

The declaration won't fail, but the initialisation might.

Alternatively, you can nest try...catch blocks, so you could declare/initialise it within an outer block and have further try...catch blocks within it.

Answer (score 1):

I wolud suggest to use `using` keyword, like this:

```
  try {
  using(StreamWriter sw = new (...)) {
     //use stream here
  }
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Using will be guarantee, by design that `StreamWriter` will be closed and disposed on exit from that block even if exception happens, cause `using` actully injects `try/finally` clause in IL. If it's not possible to do, I would seriously think to revise an architecture of calls, if it's possible.

**General rule with IO streams: Open/Use/Close in shortest time possible.**

Regards.